# Python: What does the -o command do?

Tags: python, command

I am working on a piece of Python code which makes a

```
os.system(cmd)
```

call where

```
cmd = "python apythonfile.py -o htmlfile.html folderlocation"
```

I am not sure what the -o command does.  I have tried googling it, but searching for -o brings up I/O stuff and I couldn't find the command on any general list of command pages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `-o` in this case is being passed to `apythonfile.py`; you will need to see its documentation or source in order to see what it does.

Comment: This is the definitive answer, but I think it seems reasonable, based on convention and experience, to suggest that `-o filename` is probably declaring the file to put the produced output in...

Comment: Ok thank you.  That file is actually asciidoc.py which now makes perfect sense on how it is being used.  I didn't think to look under that files help page.